# Trying to get an NSPanel from one class to be viewed in a different class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods, nspanel

I've got:

```
MyWindowController.h
MyWindowController.m
HistoryController.h
HistoryController.m
```

In MyWindowController.h, there is:

```
IBOutlet NSPanel* viewInvoice;
```

And later on:

```
- (IBAction)viewInvoice:(NSNumber *)invoiceNumber;
```

I would like to make use of this panel throughout my program.
In my HistoryController.m, there is:

```
- (IBAction)viewSelectedInvoice:(id)sender{
  id viewInvoiceObject = [[MyWindowController alloc] init];
  [viewInvoiceObject viewInvoice:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
  [viewInvoiceObject release];
}
```

Now I can successfully access that method (some NSLog calls verify this), but I'm not at all able to actually make the NSPanel appear. Here's some of the code from there:

```
- (IBAction)viewInvoice:(NSNumber *)invoiceNumber {
  [viewSelectedInvoicePanel makeKeyAndOrderFront:viewSelectedInvoicePanel];
}
```

I'm able to make the panel pop up if I link the button in my History view to the FirstResponder action "viewInvoice", however it seems like I won't be able to send through a parameter (namely the invoice number).

Answer (score 0):

Edit your HistoryController to have your custom `NSPanel` as a Property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSPanel *viewInvoice;
```

Then, create an `IBAction` on your `HistoryController` to call your custom `NSPanel` function:

```
-(IBAction)viewInvoice:(id)sender {
  [self.viewInvoice viewInvoice:self.some_property_with_invoice_number];
}
```

And link your button to the `viewInvoice` method (inside the `HistoryController` class. Also, you should change the property object type from `NSPanel` to whatever you named your class.